# Linux script check version or install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm building some app for setting up apache server with mysql, phpmyadmin, etc...
So I need a comand that will check if installation exists for example `apache2`:

1. Need to check if package is installed or if exists updated
2. Automatically install new/version package
3. Return is it installed successfully or not.

I have no expert with Linux, but so far I have this:

```
apache2 -v || {
        sudo apt install apache2 && {
            echo 'INSTALL_SUCCESS'
            exit -1
        }
    }
    echo 'NOT FOUND'
```

But to be honest, I have no idea what is happening here, but I know that it's  running installation all the time and probly there is better way to hadle this.

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing, are you really the right person to be writing this app you mention?

Comment: If this is to manage a number of hosts you control, you're going to basically reimplement config management, and might be better off learning one now (eg ansible); if it's for your customers to install your software, then that's a (potentially) separate issue (but possibly related). Otherwise, consider why this is being automated via scripting (since that's a solved problem).

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not a good idea to just install software on the user's system without their explicit consent, nor is it a good idea to automatically upgrade software, since sometimes the administrator will have pinned to a particular version for a good and valuable reason.  Additionally, updates may need to be done at certain quiet times to avoid excessive downtime.

If your program requires dependencies, then you should package it in the system package format (in this case, probably a DEB) and then declare dependencies on the software that your software needs.  For example, if you need to configure Apache, then declare a dependency on `apache2`.  Then the administrator can see the required dependencies, choose whether to install your software, and manage updates at a time and in a way that is convenient for them.  You can declare optional dependencies, such as a Recommends dependency, if the package is not required.

If you need to know whether a binary (e.g., `apache2`) exists on the system, the POSIX way to ask that is `command -v apache2`.  That is portable, works across systems, and does not invoke the binary.

If you want to know on a Debian or Ubuntu system whether a package is installed, then the correct command to do that (in this case, for `dpkg`) is this:

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Abbrev}\n' dpkg | grep -qsE '^.i'
```

That will return 0 if the package is installed or 1 if not.